# SQL Server time datatype with format

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Can I pass format for the time or date datatype in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Example: a column with time format like `hh:mm` ONLY

I searched and found that I can pass fractional second scale with like below but that is will get met a time format with seconds `hh:mm:ss` and I only want hh:mm

**Note**

I do not want to avoid this case in the select statement it wont help me in when using the column in Crystal Reports and I am not able to format it in Crystal Reports there is no date-time tab in format object option

```
_HOUR time(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to avoid this case in the select statement ... 
>   I am not able to format it in crystal report

But you do need a select statement to produce a report, so one way is to use a "style number" (8) with the convert() function - but you only want the leading 5 characters, so use char(5) for the result. i.e.

```
select convert(char(5), [datetime_or_time_column] ,8) as "hh:mm"
from thetables
```

You do not indicate at all how you gather the data for the report, but if using a temp table or stored procedure (or even a view) you can use the convert syntax above when producing the result. Note is is possible to use T-SQL's format() like so `format(getdate(),'HH:mm')` but this is usually slower than using convert().

If you have permission to add calculated columns to your table AND this wanted hh:mm data is deterministic, you could also use the convert syntax shown above for a calculated column.